# Fetch Google Search Right Side Summary Box using Python

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests

I wanted to fetch the **Right Side Summary Box of any Google Search** and I also got a unique tag i.e  for fetching it, but when I fetch the content of a Google Search Query using Python Code I don't get that right side box in the response from Google.

Please help me to fetch whole content of a Google Query:

Code for fetching Google Query Page:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.google.co.in/search?q=dhoni'
r = requests.get(url)
content = r.text
f = open('query.html','w')
f.write(search_results)
f.close()
```

PS: After you run above code and view the saved file in your browser, the right box doesn't appers which shows that in fetching page content right box content is not fetched.

Comment: You need the other javascript resources like, `xjs/_/js/k=...`

Comment: @sberry can you please explain it in detail as i am unable to understand xjs/_/js/k=...

Comment: There is another javascript resource it is trying to load, and failing.  That javascript file is needed for the right content to load correctly.  Use a proxy like Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug.

Answer (score 1):

It's not because of Javascript as [sberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372139/fetch-google-search-right-side-summary-box-using-python/69659505#comment25215090_17372139) mentioned. It's because there's no `user-agent` specified which is needed to act as a "real" user visit when the bot or browser sends a fake `user-agent` string to announce themselves as a different client (user).

Pass `user-agent`:

```py
headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

requests.get('URL', headers=headers)
```

---

Code and example in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-Search-Knowledge-Graph-python-serpapi):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    "User-agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)"
    "Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  'q': 'dhoni',
  'hl': 'en',
  'gl': 'uk'  # if set to "us" (united states) it would be a diffrent HTML layout with different CSS selectors
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

title = soup.select_one('#rhs .mfMhoc span, .qrShPb').text
subtitle = soup.select_one('.wwUB2c span').text

try:
    snippet = soup.select_one('.zsYMMe+ span').text
except: snippet = None

print(f"{title}\n{subtitle}\n{snippet}\n")

for result in soup.select(".rVusze"):
    key_element = result.select_one(".w8qArf").text

    if result.select_one(".kno-fv"):
        value_element = result.select_one(".kno-fv").text.replace(": ", "")
    else: value_element = None # or pass

    key_link = f'https://www.google.com{result.select_one(".w8qArf a")["href"]}'

    try:
        key_value_link = f'https://www.google.com{result.select_one(".kno-fv a")["href"]}'
    except: key_value_link = None # or pass

    print(f"{key_element}{value_element}\nkey_link: {key_link}\nkey_value_link: {key_value_link}")


--------------
# long output
'''
MS Dhoni
Indian cricketer
Mahendra Singh Dhoni, is a former Indian international cricketer who captained the Indian national team in limited-overs formats from 2007 to 2017 and in Test cricket from 2008 to 2014. He is widely regarded as one of the greatest in the history of cricket.

Born: 7 July 1981 (age 40 years), Ranchi, India
key_link: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=uk&q=ms+dhoni+born&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MC0wNDfWEstOttIvSM0vyEkFUkXF-XlWSflFeYtYeXOLFVIy8vMyFUB8ABdR4Gk1AAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4OPNl9vzAhXILs0KHU4yAf4Q6BMoAHoECF8QAg
key_value_link: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=uk&q=Ranchi&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MC0wNDdWAjMNS0pKzLTEspOt9AtS8wtyUoFUUXF-nlVSflHeIla2oMS85IzMHayMANdQE388AAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4OPNl9vzAhXILs0KHU4yAf4QmxMoAXoECF8QAw
Height: 1.8 m
key_link: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=uk&q=ms+dhoni+height&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MC0wNDfWks1OttIvLsgvKinWLyjKj08sychJLUm1ykjNTM8oWcTKn1uskJKRn5epABEBAAIai08-AAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4OPNl9vzAhXILs0KHU4yAf4Q6BMoAHoECHIQAg
key_value_link: None
Full name: Mahendra Singh Pansingh Dhoni
key_link: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=uk&q=ms+dhoni+full+name&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MC0wNDfWks5OttIvSM0vyEkFUkXF-XlWaaU5OQp5ibmpi1iFcosVUjLy8zIV4IIAqvu4TT8AAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4OPNl9vzAhXILs0KHU4yAf4Q6BMoAHoECHUQAg
key_value_link: None
Spouse: Sakshi Dhoni (m. 2010)
key_link: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=uk&q=ms+dhoni+spouse&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MC0wNDfWkshOttIvSM0vyEkFUkXF-XlWxQX5pcWpi1j5c4sVUjLy8zIVICIAPnRCyzkAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4OPNl9vzAhXILs0KHU4yAf4Q6BMoAHoECHQQAg
key_value_link: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=uk&q=Sakshi+Dhoni&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MC0wNDdW4gIxs0xSjIwytCSyk630C1LzC3JSgVRRcX6eVXFBfmlx6iJWnuDE7OKMTAWXjPy8zB2sjADGY2n9RQAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4OPNl9vzAhXILs0KHU4yAf4QmxMoAXoECHQQAw
Salary: 1.8 million USD (2016)
key_link: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=uk&q=ms+dhoni+salary&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MC0wNDfWks1OttIvLsgvKinWLyjKj08sychJLUm1Kk7MSSyqXMTKn1uskJKRn5epABEBAGZmveY-AAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4OPNl9vzAhXILs0KHU4yAf4Q6BMoAHoECG4QAg
key_value_link: None
Parents: Pan Singh, Devaki Devi
key_link: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=uk&q=ms+dhoni+parents&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MC0wNDfWksxOttIvSM0vyEkFUkXF-XlWBYlFqXklxYtYBXKLFVIy8vMyFaBCAFvhf287AAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4OPNl9vzAhXILs0KHU4yAf4Q6BMoAHoECGIQAg
key_value_link: https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&gl=uk&q=Pan+Singh&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MC0wNDdW4gIxsypNM0zNtSSzk630C1LzC3JSgVRRcX6eVUFiUWpeSfEiVs6AxDyF4My89IwdrIwAlGBEk0MAAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4OPNl9vzAhXILs0KHU4yAf4QmxMoAXoECGIQAw
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using 
[Google Knowledge Graph API](https://serpapi.com/knowledge-graph) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you don't have to figure out stuff and create everything from scratch, since it's already done for the end-user and the only thing that really needs to be done is just to get the data you want by accessing a structured JSON string.

Code to integrate:

```py
import os
from serpapi import GoogleSearch 

params = {
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "dhoni",
    "hl": "en",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

print(results['knowledge_graph'])

---------------
'''
{
  "title": "MS Dhoni",
  "description": "Mahendra Singh Dhoni, is a former Indian international cricketer who captained the Indian national team in limited-overs formats from 2007 to 2017 and in Test cricket from 2008 to 2014. He is widely regarded as one of the greatest in the history of cricket.",
  "source": {
    "name": "Wikipedia",
    "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_Dhoni"
  },
  "born": "July 7, 1981 (age 40 years), Ranchi, India",
  "born_links": [
    {
      "text": "Ranchi, India",
      "link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Ranchi&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAOPgE-LUz9U3MC0wNDdWAjMNS0pKzLTEspOt9AtS8wtyUoFUUXF-nlVSflHeIla2oMS85IzMHayMANdQE388AAAA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOzafLmNvzAhWignIEHY5ZBMcQmxMoAHoFCJUBEAI"
    }
  ]
... # other data
}
'''
```

---

You can read more about it in the blog post I wrote about [how to reduce the chance of being blocked while web scraping](http://in%20order%20to%20get%20the%20actual%20response%20(output/text/data)%20that%20you%20see%20in%20the%20browser%20you%20need%20to%20send%20additional%20headers,%20more%20specific:%20user-agent%20which%20is%20needed%20to%20act%20as%20a%20%22real%22%20user%20visit%20when%20bot%20or%20browser%20sends%20a%20fake%20user-agent%20string%20to%20announce%20themselves%20as%20a%20different%20client.%20%20You%20can%20read%20more%20about%20it%20in%20the%20blog%20post%20I%20wrote%20about%20how%20to%20reduce%20the%20chance%20of%20being%20blocked%20while%20web%20scraping.).

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this code simply does not work